# Get data from listobject, sorted and filtered by multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

With the help of the wonderfull community of Stafoverflow, I was able to put together the macro below, that retrieves ListObject information, sorted and filtered by multiple criteria. And it's instant by the way, super fast.

Sorting works great. The problem is with the filter, because I need to filter by 3 columns, but only if the filter for that column is <>""

Below i've left sFilterSubSection ="" so I don't aply filter for that column.

```
    'SAMPLE DATA
    sFilterWorksheet = "Global Inputs"
    sFilterSection = "GA"
    sFilterSubSection = ""
```

I've started with the code below, but I noticed that it's not a good solution, as every time
I apply the filter, i'm left with less rows comparing to `LO.ListColumns("Worksheet").DataBodyRange`.

```
        If sFilterWorksheet <> "" Then
            arrResult = .Filter(arrResult, .XLookup(LO.ListColumns("Worksheet").DataBodyRange, sFilterWorksheet, True, False))
        End If
```

Is there a way to apply multiple filters in VBA using the WorksheetFunction.Filter method?

````
Sub inputs_getTableFilteredAndSorted()  '(Optional sFilterWorksheet As String, Optional sFilterSection As String, Optional sFilterSubSection As String)
    Dim LO As ListObject, arrResult
    
    Set LO = inputs_getListObject
    'sOrderBy = "[Worksheet order],[Section order],[SubSection order],[Title rows order],[Title columns order]"
    Dim sFilterWorksheet, sFilterSection, sFilterSubSection
    
    'SAMPLE DATA
    sFilterWorksheet = "Global Inputs"
    sFilterSection = "GA"
    sFilterSubSection = ""
    
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        arrResult = LO.DataBodyRange
            
        'FILTERING
        If sFilterWorksheet <> "" Then
            arrResult = .Filter(arrResult, .XLookup(LO.ListColumns("Worksheet").DataBodyRange, sFilterWorksheet, True, False))
        End If
        If sFilterSection <> "" Then
            arrResult = .Filter(arrResult, .XLookup(LO.ListColumns("Section").DataBodyRange, sFilterSection, True, False))
        End If
        If sFilterSubSection <> "" Then
            arrResult = .Filter(arrResult, .XLookup(LO.ListColumns("SubSection").DataBodyRange, sFilterSubSection, True, False))
        End If
        
        'SORTING
        arrResult = .Sort(.Sort(.Sort(.Sort(.Sort(arrResult, _
            LO.ListColumns("Title columns order").Index, 1), _
            LO.ListColumns("Title rows order").Index, 1), _
            LO.ListColumns("SubSection order").Index, 1), _
            LO.ListColumns("Section order").Index, 1), _
            LO.ListColumns("Worksheet order").Index, 1)

    End With
End Sub
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my question using Evaluate, and creating the string used for evaluate separatelly, depending on the available variables

```
Sub inputs_getTableFilteredAndSorted()  '(Optional sFilterWorksheet As String, Optional sFilterSection As String, Optional sFilterSubSection As String)
    Dim LO As ListObject, arrResult, arrBoolWs, arrBoolSection, arrBoolSubsection, arrBool
    Dim R As Long, C As Long, sEvaluate As String
    
    Set LO = inputs_getListObject
    'sOrderBy = "[Worksheet order],[Section order],[SubSection order],[Title rows order],[Title columns order]"
    Dim sFilterWorksheet, sFilterSection, sFilterSubSection
    
    'SAMPLE DATA
    sFilterWorksheet = "Global Inputs"
    sFilterSection = "GA"
    sFilterSubSection = ""
    
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        arrResult = LO.DataBodyRange
            
        'FILTERING
        '   - PREPARE STIRNG TO BE EVALUATED, SHAPE  "=FILTER(range,(columnAddress1="value1")*(columnAddress2>"value2"))
        sEvaluate = "(" & LO.ListColumns("Worksheet").DataBodyRange.Address & "=""" & sFilterWorksheet & """)"
        If sFilterSection <> "" Then
            sEvaluate = sEvaluate & "*" & "(" & LO.ListColumns("Section").DataBodyRange.Address & "=""" & sFilterSection & """)"
        End If
        If sFilterSubSection <> "" Then
            sEvaluate = sEvaluate & "*" & "(" & LO.ListColumns("SubSection").DataBodyRange.Address & "=""" & sFilterSubSection & """)"
        End If
        
        '   - EVALUATE THE STRING
        arrBool = Evaluate(sEvaluate)

        '   - APPLY FILTER
        arrResult = .Filter(arrResult, arrBool)
                
        'SORTING
        arrResult = .Sort(.Sort(.Sort(.Sort(.Sort(arrResult, _
            LO.ListColumns("Title columns order").Index, 1), _
            LO.ListColumns("Title rows order").Index, 1), _
            LO.ListColumns("SubSection order").Index, 1), _
            LO.ListColumns("Section order").Index, 1), _
            LO.ListColumns("Worksheet order").Index, 1)

    End With
End Sub
```